# Is tensor product commutative on orthonormal basis?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

In general the tensor product $\varphi\otimes\psi$ is not commutative, but I was thinking that if I have tensor product on two orthonormal bases of Hilbert spaces are they commutative i.e is $$\varphi_i\otimes\varphi_j=\varphi_j\otimes\varphi_i$$ and if so why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these are two vectors in a same natural basis (consisting of *all* $\varphi_i\otimes\varphi_j$) for the tensor product space, they are obviously distinct.